# HttpWebRequest - how can I escape the vertical bar (pipe) character in the URI

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, encode

in my code:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.org/1|2|3");
```

and in Fiddler, I see that the URI is always encoded to:
"http://example.com/1%7C2%7C3" while I want to send "http://example.org/1|2|3"

I tried using HttpUtility to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString("http://example.org/1|2|3")); 
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Update: Try to enable IRI parsing as well. Add this to your app.config/web.config:

```
<uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
</uri>
```

If you use a .NET version below 4, you also have to add this for the uri-section to be valid:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System,
                      Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: See updated answer. Enabling IRI parsing extends the allowed character set in an URI (technically making it an IRI). This should allow the unencoded pipe symbol.

Comment: That didn't work either, tried targeting both 4.5 and 4.0. The more I search, the more I think that this might not be possible in .Net

Answer (score 0):

It will encode every character that is not from the standard ones, to read the url in your server/receiver you can use HttpUtility.UrlDecode() and then do what ever.

Comment: From what I'm reading the pipe, "|", is not an illegal character in an URL, so I should be able to send it